# Multiple unique dropdown security questions in REACT.js

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am trying to generate a series of security questions. I have a pool of available questions. There will be three such question dropdown list in my webpage. Q1,Q2,Q3.
I am able to build that quite correctly. Using react select.

However, the problem is when I am selecting one question in Q1. I want that question not to be available in the dropdown for Q2. However everytime it appears the same set. Howcan I remove the already selected questions from the list.?

```
             class dropdownqs extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { 
        options :  [
            { value: ‘What was your childhood nickname?’, label: ‘What was your childhood nickname?’ },
                { value: ‘In what city did you meet your spouse/significant other?’, label: ‘In what city did you meet your spouse/significant other?’},
                { value: ‘What is the name of your favorite childhood friend?’, label: ‘What is the name of your favorite childhood friend?’},
                { value: ‘What street did you live on in third grade?’, label: ‘What street did you live on in third grade?’},
                { value: ‘What is the middle name of your youngest child?’, label: ‘What is the middle name of your youngest child?’ },
                { value: ‘What is the middle name of your oldest sibling?’, label: ‘What is the middle name of your oldest sibling?’},
                { value: ‘What school did you attend for sixth grade?’, label: ‘What school did you attend for sixth grade’ },
                { value: ‘What was the name of your first stuffed animal?’, label: ‘What was the name of your first stuffed animal?’ },
                { value: ‘In what city or town did your mather and father meet?’, label: ‘In what city or town did your mather and father meet?’ }
              ]
    }
    this.handleChangeqs1 = this.handleChangeqs1.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeqs2 = this.handleChangeqs2.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeqs3 = this.handleChangeqs3.bind(this);


    // function
    handleChangeqs1(selectedOption){
    // this.setState({ selectedOption});
    this.setState({ selectedOptionqs1: selectedOption });
    var i;
    var array = this.state.options;
    for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(array[i].value==selectedOption.value){
            array.splice(i,1)
            this.setState({
                options: array
            })
            break;
        }
    }
  }
   // function
   handleChangeqs2(selectedOption) {
    //this.setState({ selectedOption});
    this.setState({ selectedOptionqs2:selectedOption });
    var i;
    var array = this.state.options;
    for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(array[i].value==selectedOption.value){
            array.splice(i,1)
            this.setState({
                options: array
            })
            break;
        }
    }
  }
  // function
  handleChangeqs3(selectedOption) {
    //this.setState({ selectedOption});
    this.setState({ selectedOptionqs3 : selectedOption });
    var i;
    var array = this.state.options;
    for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(array[i].value==selectedOption.value){
            array.splice(i,1)
            this.setState({
                options: array
            })
            break;
        }
    }
  }
 render() {
 const { selectedOption } = this.state;
    return (
 <div className=“App”>
  {/* BODY */}
            <body className=“App-body-register”>



          {/* SECURITY QUESTIONS  */}
            <div align=“left”>
                 {/* 1st Security Question */}
                <h3>
                    Security question 1
                </h3>
                {/* //select question */}
                <Select
                    id=“Question1select”
                    editable={false}
                    value={selectedOption} 
                    onChange={this.handleChangeqs1.bind(this)}
                    options={this.state.options}
                />

                {/* //input answer */}
                <input type=“text” className=“App-login-input” id=“security1ans”  minlength=“4" maxlength=“20”
                    placeholder=“Must be a minimum of 4 characters long” required/>
                <span class=“validity”></span>


                {/* // 2nd Security Question */}
                <h3>
                    Security question 2
                </h3>
                {/* //select question  */}
                <Select
                    value={selectedOption} 
                    onChange={this.handleChangeqs2.bind(this)}
                    options={this.state.options}
                />
                {/* //input answer */}
                <input type=“text” className=“App-login-input” id=“security2ans”  minlength=“4” maxlength=“20"
                placeholder=“Must be a minimum of 4 characters long” required/>
                <span class=“validity”></span>

                {/* // 3rd Security Question */}
                <h3>
                    Security question 3
                </h3>
                {/* //select question */}
                <Select
                    value={selectedOption} 
                    onChange={this.handleChangeqs3.bind(this)}
                    options={this.state.options}
                />
                {/* //input answer */}
                <input type=“text” className=“App-login-input” id=“security3ans”  minlength=“4" maxlength=“20”
                placeholder=“Must be a minimum of 4 characters long” required/>
                <span class=“validity”></span>
            </div>
        </body>
        </div>
    );
}
   export default dropdownqs;
```

I was following the code in https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select

Comment: Can you show us your attempted implementation of the component using <Select>?

Comment: `<Select
                       id=“Question1select”
                       editable={false}
                       value={selectedOption}
                       onChange={this.handleChangeqs1.bind(this)}
                       options={this.state.options}
                   />   `

Comment: Can you edit the original post to include the full code of the component using Select?

Comment: Done @ShawnAndrews

Answer (score 1):

To have 3 input `select`'s where each cannot select an option chosen by the rest of the `select`'s you'll want to start by adding a new property to your existing state that holds all the already chosen questions.

Once we know the options already chosen by all `select`'s we can begin with all possible questions then filter out those questions already chosen via the `filter` function:

```
getAvailableOptions = () => {
    const availableOptionsLeft = this.state.filterOptions;
    return availableOptionsLeft.filter(questionOption => {
      return this.state.questionVals.indexOf(questionOption) === -1;
    });
};
```

Demonstration: https://codesandbox.io/s/yvv3y14x09

Comment: Thanks a lot. Was stuck on this issue for 2 hours.

Comment: No worries:) Dont forget to mark it as Answered so others know it will work for them